# Row Number calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I would like to be able to SQL code the Cycle column in the picture below. If the same ID is used within 2 minutes, it will be part of that same cycle. I've used `RowNumber()` a lot but not sure it's that straight forward. I could create a new Time column that assigns the same number if the time is within 2 minutes of each other, but perhaps there is a better way.

[image]

Comment: The `time` column isn't a `time`, it's just a number. How does that number translate to an actual time?

Comment: Looks like 24HHMMSS

Comment: @rhaug2, hello and welcome! Please edit your post and include create/insert for your data also include what you've already tried to solve the problem.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: What if there are three rows each <2 minutes apart but >2 minutes total?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm certain there are better ways of doing this, but this is the one I landed on. If you change your time as integer column to time as time, it will be easier for you in the long run.

```
create table #t (id int, event_time_text nvarchar(6), event_time time);

insert into #t (id,event_time_text) values 
(123456789,'070007'),
(123456789,'070048'),
(123456789,'162455'),
(123456789,'162542'),
(123456789,'184131'),
(123456789,'184207');

update #t set event_time = TIMEFROMPARTS(LEFT(event_time_text,2),SUBSTRING(event_time_text,3,2),SUBSTRING(event_time_text,5,2),0,0);

WITH dat --calculate the difference in minutes of one row from the previous row
AS
(
SELECT *
    ,CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(minute,LAG(event_time,1,event_time) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY event_time),event_time) <= 2 
        THEN LAG(event_time,1,event_time) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY event_time) 
        ELSE event_time
     END AS diff_index
FROM #t
)
SELECT *
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY diff_index) AS group_within_id
FROM dat;
```

[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7f840565903246945b6c5cad466cb9a6)